# console.log doesn't run in a function that is assigned to a button with "onclick"

Tags: javascript, console.log

I have a $10 button `<button onclick="$10Wager">$10</button>` that the user clicks if he wants to wager $10 and $10 will be deducted from his chips

The code in js:

```
let player = {
    name: "Per",
    chips: 200
}

function $10Wager(){
    return player.chips -= 10
    console.log(player.chips)
}
```

Why doesn't the final value of the player's chips after deduction of the $10 wager (i.e. 190) display on the console? could u also explain the logic?

What code should I use to ensure that the $10 button is working?

Comment: `console.log` is unreachable code. `return` stops the execution of the function.

Comment: what do u mean by unreachable? what should i use to test if the button is actually working?

Comment: Update the value first, and then log it.

Comment: After `return` nothing executed  and it is unreachable. try this: `function $10Wager() {player.chips -= 10; console.log(player.chips); return player;}`

Comment: look at my working snippet. also change `onclick="$10Wager"` to `onclick="$10Wager()"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this code**

*You use JS function but when you calling you function using `onclick` here you forget to use 
 `fucntion brackets ()`*

```js
    let player = {
        name: "Per",
        chips: 200
    }

  function $10Wager(){
    player.chips -= 10
    console.log(player.chips);
    return player.chips;
}
```

```html
  <button onclick="$10Wager()">$10</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

After `return` all code is unreachable. It means `return` stops the execution of the rest of the function. so put `return` at the end of the function.

Also you forgot to add `()` on the function:

```
 <button onclick="$10Wager()">$10</button>
```

Here is working sample:

```js
    let player = {
        name: "Per",
        chips: 200
    }
    
    function $10Wager(){
        player.chips -= 10
        console.log(player.chips);
        return player.chips;
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="$10Wager()">$10</button>
```